# What's the difference between `==` and `is`?

Tags: python

i am confused with the usage of `==` and `is`.

```
default_netrc = file is None
if file is None:
    try:
        file = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], ".netrc")
    except KeyError:
        raise IOError("Could not find .netrc: $HOME is not set")
```

Here is the code snap.

Is this line `default_netrc = file is None` is equal `default_netrc = file == None`?

when compare with `None`, should we use `is` or `==`?

Answer (score 0):

`a is b` returns `id(a)==id(b)`, which is true if the labels point to the same object. `a==b` returns true if the (potentially different) objects pointed to by a and b are equivalent in a way defined by the objects being compared.